# Return to the top of inner while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Hi~ I'm new to python and I'm working on my summative.
I'm basically creating a text-based game that involves lots of while loops, and if statements inside the while loops.I want to return to the top of a inner while loop(there are lots of inner loops in my program though, but the program always returns to the top of the outermost loop, which looks like:

```
    Tester=True
    While Tester:
```

The part of the program that is inside a while loop is under an if statement, which basically looks like:

```
    if(X==1):
             continue
    if(X==2):
             break
```

So, I used continue, trying to make it go back to the inner loop, but it always returns to "Tester=True".
Can someone tell me how to fix this? Thank you very much!

I'm not going to post my code here because my teacher does not want us to do so, sorry about that.

Comment: If you cannot post your actual code can you simplify the code to the minimum that exhibits your problem?

Comment: Can you at least show us code with 2 while loops. If the if statements are indeed with in 2 nested while loops `continue` should bring you back to the top of the inner loop.

Comment: Why do you think `it always returns to "Tester=True"`? Can you be sure about that? AFAIK there's nothing you can do in a `while` loop to achieve that behavior.

Comment: It really is unclear what you're asking. Your question will get shut down soon if you do not clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to use Generators. [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Comment: Well when wants to continue from where he left he could do `next()` for getting started from the point he left.

Comment: So where should I put next()?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is really unclear but i think that defining a function will help you a lot.

you can define a function with `def function():` and call it when you need to.

[tutorial and description here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)